# Unable to send data using SimpleTCP

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to create a TCP/IP client/server app that runs on my computer.The server seems to works perfectly but the client can't send any data.

Here is my code for the client:

```cs
using SimpleTCP;
using System.Text;

namespace Client
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        // implementing simple tcp client
        SimpleTcpClient client;
        //SimpleTcpServer server;
        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnConnect.Enabled = false;
           // server.Start();

            
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //btnSend.Enabled = false;
            client = new SimpleTcpClient();
            client.StringEncoder = Encoding.UTF8;
            client.DataReceived += Client_DataReceived;
        }

        private void Client_DataReceived(object? sender, SimpleTCP.Message e)
        {
            textStatus.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
            {
                textStatus.Text += e.MessageString;
                
            });
        }

        private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            client.Write(textMessage.Text);
         
        }
    }
}
```

Here is code for the server:

```cs
using SimpleTCP;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TCPIPDemo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (server.IsStarted)
            {
                server.Stop();
            }
        }
        // implementing simpletcpserver class
        SimpleTcpServer server;
        
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            server = new SimpleTcpServer();
            server.Delimiter = 0x13;
            server.StringEncoder = Encoding.UTF8;
            server.DataReceived += Server_DataReceived;

                }

        private void Server_DataReceived(object? sender, SimpleTCP.Message e)
        {
            textStatus.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
            {
                textStatus.Text += e.MessageString;
                e.ReplyLine(string.Format("You said:{0}",e.MessageString));
            });
            
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textStatus.Text += "Server starting ...";
            //System.Net.IPAddress ip = new System.Net.IPAddress(long.Parse(textHost.Text));
            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(textHost.Text);
            server.Start(ip, Convert.ToInt32(textPort.Text));

        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is the following:

> System.Exception: 'Cannot send data to a null TcpClient (check to see if Connect was called)'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is described quite clearly in the exception. You need to call `.Connect(URL, PORT)` on a new instance of `SimpleTcpClient` before using it.

For example:

```
var client = new SimpleTcpClient().Connect("127.0.0.1", 8910);
```

The official GitHub has more information, please check their [readme](https://github.com/BrandonPotter/SimpleTCP).

Comment: thanks a lot but what if i want to receive the ip & port from input?

Comment: You can pass variables as values for the `.Connect`-Method

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a call to connect the client to the server, there is a Connect method with arguments to provide address and port

https://github.com/BrandonPotter/SimpleTCP/blob/master/SimpleTCP/SimpleTcpClient.cs#L34